How to make tab layout indicator padding
I'm going to make android app
so I use tabLayout(com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout)
when i set tabPaddingStart 16dp, tabPaddingEnd 16dp
then tab indicator width  also apply padding
how to make it?
enter image description here

Create a custom drawable for tab tabIndicator
Through this you can set the size, height and split padding of the tabindicator.
 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layoutdiet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_38sdp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_38sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/_2sdp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />


Create a custom drawable tab_indicator.xml use desire custom width.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape>
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_55sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_2sdp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

